# Android : Color of fonts on preview window and real device are different

Tags: android, android-studio

As you can see in the image that font color on emulator is totally black but on preview window textview at top have slightly light blue color and at the bottom text has white font. I have tested this app on two real device and i am facing the same black font problem.
I hope you guys will help to get out of this problem.
here's the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.myfirstcard.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ghat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Oldest City Of The World."
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textColor="#03a9f4"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Incredible Varanasi!"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, it's not a real device. It's just a virtual machine.

Comment: Rendering engine in preview screen is optimized in such a way that you can actually see anything during development. In emulator it will looks different and on the device it will depends from device screen itself.

Comment: I have tested the app on two real devices the font color still appears to be black. Actually i have recent started learning android from Android app for beginners from udacity.com the app appears to be correct on the instructor device but she is using older version of android studio 1.x and i am using android studio 2.1.1. Suggest me some ways to get rid of problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your xml layout as i have copy pasted and run it on an actual device. I am thinking that the problem is in your java class. Try checking your java class because i think you are programmatically overriding your **TextView** color.

Comment: I think you caught actually where is the problem in my code. I have checked my apps java folder it contain three  java file(1.ApplicationTest.java 2.ExampleUnitTest.java 3.MainActivity.java). I am novice in programming and android so, i hope you will suggest me necessary change in my java class to get rid of problem. Ask me if you need to look through java class code.

Comment: add the java classes on your question so we could see if it is actually overriding the xml **TextView** color.

Comment: ApplicationTest.java :- 'package com.example.android.happybirthday;

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }
}'

Comment: ExampleUnitTest.java :- package com.example.android.happybirthday;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * To work on unit tests, switch the Test Artifact in the Build Variants view.
 */
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }

Comment: MainActivity.java :- package com.example.android.happybirthday;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: @AkashSeth Add your Java code not here in the comments. It is not properly formated and unreadable. Just [edit] (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38112114/edit) your question to add it there. If still relevant to the problem.

Comment: this is no good, edit your question and add the codes there. do not put it on the comments it is a pain tracing it.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the problem by myself actually to successfully run the app you need to have same android version sdk installed in your android studio as in my case i have sdk for android marshmallow 6.0 but i was trying to run the app on a android Lollipop 5.1 device.